# how to call the thread from a different function pyqt5

Tags: python, pyqt5

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication,  QPlainTextEdit, QApplication, QMainWindow, QLabel, QComboBox
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap
from pynput import keyboard
from pynput.keyboard import Listener, Controller
import pyperclip as pc 

keyboard = Controller()
class App(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(App, self).__init__(parent)
        #super().__init__()
        label = QLabel(self)
        pixmap = QPixmap('E:/copycat/new.png')
        label.setPixmap(pixmap)
        label.setGeometry(0,0,900,400) 
        self.title = 'COPYCAT'
        self.left = 10
        self.top = 10
        self.width = 400
        self.height = 140
        self.initUI()
        self.key()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
        self.setGeometry(self.left, self.top, self.width, self.height)
        ###########
        combo = QComboBox(self)
        shotcut_list = ["Key.f9","Key.f2","Key.f3","Key.f4","Key.f5","Key.f6","Key.f7","Key.f8","Key.f1","Key.f10","Key.f11","Key.f12"]
        combo.addItems(shotcut_list)
        global shortcut
        global cptext
        shortcut = combo.currentText()
        combo.setGeometry(350, 120, 120, 30)
        combo.activated[str].connect(self.onChanged)  
        # Create textbox
        self.textbox = QPlainTextEdit(self)
        self.textbox.move(20, 160)
        self.textbox.setReadOnly(True)
        self.textbox.resize(500,205)
        self.setGeometry(70,70,540,388)
        self.show()

    def onChanged(self, text):
        global shortcut
        shortcut=text
        
    def print_key(self,key):
        if str(key) == shortcut:
            cptext = pc.paste() 
            keyboard.type(cptext)
            self.textbox.insertPlainText(cptext)
            self.textbox.insertPlainText("\n")

    def key(self):    
        listener = Listener(on_press=self.print_key)
        listener.start()
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = App()
    #ex.key()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

The above code shows an error when I update the textbox from the print_key function
It shows this error:

```
Cannot queue arguments of type 'QTextBlock'
(Make sure 'QTextBlock' is registered using qRegisterMetaType()
Cannot queue arguments of type 'QTextCursor'
(Make sure 'QTextCursor' is registered using qRegisterMetaType()
```

Comment: Access UI elements is not allowed from external threads. In any case, why are you using pynput for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The callback associated with on_press is executed in a secondary thread so your implementation is updating the GUI from a secondary thread which Qt prohibits, instead you should use the signals as they are thread-safe.

```py
import sys
import threading

from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSignal, pyqtSlot, QObject
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (
    QApplication,
    QComboBox,
    QLabel,
    QMainWindow,
    QPlainTextEdit,
)

from pynput.keyboard import Listener, Controller
import pyperclip as pc


class KeyboardListener(QObject):
    textChanged = pyqtSignal(str)

    def __init__(self, shortcut, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self._shortcut = shortcut

        listener = Listener(on_press=self.handle_pressed)
        listener.start()
        self.mutex = threading.Lock()

    @property
    def shortcut(self):
        return self._shortcut

    def handle_pressed(self, key):
        with self.mutex:
            if str(key) == self.shortcut:
                cptext = pc.paste()
                self.textChanged.emit(cptext)

    @pyqtSlot(str)
    def update_shortcut(self, shortcut):
        with self.mutex:
            self._shortcut = shortcut


class App(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(App, self).__init__(parent)
        # super().__init__()
        label = QLabel(self)
        pixmap = QPixmap("E:/copycat/new.png")
        label.setPixmap(pixmap)
        label.setGeometry(0, 0, 900, 400)
        self.title = "COPYCAT"
        self.left = 10
        self.top = 10
        self.width = 400
        self.height = 140
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
        self.setGeometry(self.left, self.top, self.width, self.height)
        ###########
        combo = QComboBox(self)
        shotcut_list = [
            "Key.f9",
            "Key.f2",
            "Key.f3",
            "Key.f4",
            "Key.f5",
            "Key.f6",
            "Key.f7",
            "Key.f8",
            "Key.f1",
            "Key.f10",
            "Key.f11",
            "Key.f12",
        ]
        combo.addItems(shotcut_list)

        shortcut = combo.currentText()
        combo.setGeometry(350, 120, 120, 30)
        self.textbox = QPlainTextEdit(self)
        self.textbox.move(20, 160)
        self.textbox.setReadOnly(True)
        self.textbox.resize(500, 205)
        self.setGeometry(70, 70, 540, 388)

        self.keyboard = Controller()

        self.listener = KeyboardListener(combo.currentText())
        combo.activated[str].connect(self.listener.update_shortcut)
        self.listener.textChanged.connect(self.handle_text_changed)

    @pyqtSlot(str)
    def handle_text_changed(self, text):
        self.textbox.insertPlainText(text)
        self.textbox.insertPlainText("\n")
        self.keyboard.type(text)


def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = App()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot sir, can you help me to know from where should i begin with python and pyqt5